# RecyclerView jump when item size changes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have stumbled upon a problem regarding the `RecyclerView`. The situation is as follows:

1. I navigate from one `Activity` to another, the second one having a `RecyclerView`
2. The second activity reads an index out of the `Intent` and jumps its `RecyclerView` to that position (so it may "start" in the middle, from the user perspective)
3. The `RecyclerView` houses a list of news, each one having a network-obtained thumbnail
4. The thumbnails are obtained using *Glide*, with a placeholder (so a `View` inside a `ViewHolder` is at first inflated with height X, which may change after the thumbnail is obtained)

Now the problem is that when the user scrolls up from the item they started up, the `ViewHolder` is created and *Glide* makes a request for a thumbnail. It results in the list item having some height and changing it a second later, after the thumbnail is obtained, which in turn results in a nasty "jump" (because of the size change). It only happens 3-4 times, until enough `ViewHolders` get created to handle the whole `RecyclerView`.

Any idea how to prevent this? Ideally I would like to make the item above current to expand upwards.

I already tried making the items stack from the bottom, but it does not solve the issue, just makes it happen for the below items instead of the above ones. Also, I can not and don't want to predict the size of the obtained thumbnail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a place holder image in the Recycled View. And replace that image when it becomes available (downloaded).

This only works of course if you know the size of the tumbnails.

Comment: As I said in the question, there is a placeholder, but it is not the same size as the final thumbnail :-( I am hoping to get some different ideas, as precalculating the size of the obtained thumbnail is a bit tricky and anti-patternish :-(

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your question properly. 
Can't you resize them to the same size and use one placeholder?

Comment: I could, but I want to avoid that if possible, which is why I asked the question :-)

Comment: Sorry I'm not being too helpful here :). The only thing I could think of is to make it animate. When the real thumbnail is downloaded you check if it's size is different from your placeholder and if it is then use an item animator to change the size smoothly.

Comment: You are helpful in making me realise that it may be the only way ^^

Comment: I ended up precalculating the ImageView height (I do not know the size of the thumbnail, but I do know the aspect ratio) and it works fine. I guess your answer could be interpreted as doing this, so here is your 15 rep :-D